# How to Sort a list Left to Right and then Top to bottom

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, list, sorting

I've gathered some coordinates (x,y) in a list and need to sort them left to right, top down in reading order.  The attached image shows what I'm aiming for.

I thought the below would work but it's not ordering them correctly. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
mypointlist = mypointlist.OrderByDescending(pnt => pnt.X).ThenBy(pnt => pnt.Y).ToList();
```

[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bW75g.jpg)

Comment: how is it appearing with your present code.

Comment: This looks correct , only thing i think needs to change is use OrderBy instead of OrderByDescending.

Comment: Tried the different options. I think the problem lies with my x coordinates and y coordinates being the same for each row / column (as applicable).  Not sure. Something is throwing it off though. eg. x values for 1,5,9, and 13 are the same, and y values for 1,2,3, and 4 are the same.

Answer (score 2):

You need to sort them by Y ascending (Top to Down), Then by X ascending (To order the points with the same Y from Left to Right):

```
mypointlist = mypointlist.OrderBy(pnt => pnt.Y).ThenBy(pnt => pnt.X).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to have worked in my particular case, but I'm not sure it's full proof:

```
mypointlist = mypointlist.OrderByDescending(pnt => pnt.Y).ThenBy(pnt => pnt.X).ToList();
```